# extends public static property

Tags: php

I want to extends a php7.1 static property's class in order to have this example running.

```
<?php

class mother {
    const ONE   = 1;
    const TWO   = 2;
    const THREE = 3;

    public static $desc = [
        1 => 'one',
        2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three'
    ];
}

class children extends mother {
    const FOUR = 4;

    // how to "extends" mother::$desc ??? 
}

echo children::$desc[children::THREE];
echo children::$desc[children::FOUR];
exit(0);
```

Output :

```
three
Notice: Undefined offset: 4
```

What do I have to put in "children" class in order to have

```
three
four
```

?

I tried several syntax but since I don't know what I'm doing nor what I have to search, every attempt failed.
It seem that magic function can help me but I don't see how.

Comment: @AbraCadaver No, deceze answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to "extend" the parent array inline; all you can do is redeclare it:

```
class children extends mother {
    const FOUR = 4;

    public static $desc = [
        1 => 'one',
        2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three',
        4 => 'four'
    ];
}
```

You can do it more dynamically after the fact:

```
class children extends mother {
    const FOUR = 4;

    public static $desc = null;
}

children::$desc = mother::$desc + [4 => 'four'];
```

Comment: Thank you. Too bad that I can't  do it directly at children::$desc declaration, but it fit my need perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

[deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) has a good take, or you can implement a getter:

```
class mother {
    const ONE   = 1;
    const TWO   = 2;
    const THREE = 3;

    public static $desc = [
        1 => 'one',
        2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three'
    ];
}

class children extends mother {
    const FOUR = 4;

    public static function get_desc() {
        return static::$desc + [4 => 'four'];
    }
}

echo children::get_desc()[children::THREE];
echo children::get_desc()[children::FOUR];
```

Or alternately, a getter and child variable:

```
class children extends mother {
    const FOUR = 4;
    public static $child_desc = [4 => 'four'];

    public static function get_desc() {
        return static::$desc + static::$child_desc;
    }
}
```